# Won't decrypt to the same string

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TransmogrifierChained {
    private Random mixer;
    private int xorValue;

    public TransmogrifierChained(long key) {
        mixer = new Random(key);
        xorValue = mixer.nextInt() & 0x7F;
    }

    public char mutate(char c) {
        int asciiValue = (int) c;
        int mutatedValue = asciiValue ^ xorValue;
        xorValue = mixer.nextInt() & 0x7F; // generate new xor value
        return (char) mutatedValue;
    }

    public String mutate(String message) {
        StringBuilder encrypted = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : message.toCharArray()) {
            encrypted.append(mutate(c));
        }
        return encrypted.toString();
    }

    public String encrypt(String message) {
        return mutate(message);
    }

    public String decrypt(String message) {
        StringBuilder decrypted = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : message.toCharArray()) {
            decrypted.append(mutate(c));
        }
        return decrypted.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long key = 123456;
        TransmogrifierChained transmogrifier = new TransmogrifierChained(key);

        String message = "Hello World!";
        System.out.println("Original message: " + message);

        String encrypted = transmogrifier.encrypt(message);
        System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + encrypted);

        String decrypted = transmogrifier.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypted message: " + decrypted);
    }
}
```

Hi guys my code outputs this:

```
Original message: Hello World!
Encrypted message: o:&b_D.JRS\
Decrypted message: *S=N&QP39
```

It should output:

```
Original message: Hello World!
Encrypted message: -the correct encryption-
Decrypted message: Hello World!
```

Comment: Well, the first experiment would be to comment out the line `xorValue = mixer.nextInt() & 0x7F; ` - without this line, the decryption succeeds. This narrows it down - now you can look into why this way of updating the `xorValue` leads to your observed behavior.

Comment: When you keep using the same `transmogrifier`, it keeps generating new random numbers. So not the same random numbers for decryption as it used for encryption.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinitialize your `mixer` to produce the same sequence used during encryption. One easy way to do this without changing the `TransmogrifierChained` class is to just create a new instance for decryption:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long key = 123456;
    TransmogrifierChained transmogrifier = new TransmogrifierChained(key);

    String message = "Hello World!";
    System.out.println("Original message: " + message);

    String encrypted = transmogrifier.encrypt(message);
    System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + encrypted);

    transmogrifier = new TransmogrifierChained(key); // new instance!
    String decrypted = transmogrifier.decrypt(encrypted);
    System.out.println("Decrypted message: " + decrypted);
}
```

Yields something like

```
Original message: Hello World!
Encrypted message: o:&b_D.JRS\
Decrypted message: Hello World!
```